# DotNetNuke Error: Document.load() is deprecated

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am receiving an error:

> Use of Document.load() is deprecated. To upgrade your code, use the DOM XMLHttpRequest object. For more help https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest
>   https://www.boldgroup.com/
>   Line 83

When attempting to load my website in Chrome, I also get this error in Firefox. This is causing the website background to not display and the menu's to not display correctly. How can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that script is coming from your skin (minimalist-gray-glass).  Try using a different skin, or checking with the skin developer to see if there is an update.